# Free/Open-Source Theme Frameworks as an Alternate to Thesis?

Tags: themes, theme-recommendation

What good free and open source alternatives exist to the Thesis theme  ??

Comment: There are hundreds of free and open source themes available, many with custom functionality.  So what features of Thesis do you want your "alternative" to have?  Without knowing *how* you'll use the theme, this question is a little too broad ...

Comment: Suggestion to edit the title?  "Free/Open-Source Theme Frameworks as an Alternate to Thesis?"

Comment: Afaik, thesis Is GPL...

Comment: @Ionut It is not completely GPL.

Comment: @shubhkarman: indeed, but the php code is :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume by "*alternatives*" you mean [Theme](http://wpcandy.com/uncategorized/frameworks-child-themes-filters-and-hook) [Frameworks](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/wordpress-theme-frameworks)?  If yes, here's a list:

- [Atahualpa](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/atahualpa)
- [The Buffet Framework](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/the-buffet-framework)
- [Carrington](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/carrington-blog)
- [Hybrid](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/hybrid)
- [Sandbox](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/sandbox)
- [Thematic](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/thematic)
- [WP Framework](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/wp-framework)

**UPDATE:** I added a few more:

- [ashford](http://ashford.turtleinteractive.com/)
- [Basis](http://wpbasis.de/)
- [Brave New World](http://www.thatstandardsguy.co.uk/blog/2009/04/brave-new-world-wordpress-theme/)
- [Buffet](http://www.zy.sg/the-buffet-framework/)
- [Imagination](http://www.cssjockey.com/imagination/)
- [Naked](http://www.siftware.co.uk/services/wordpress/blank-wordpress-theme/)
- [OnePress](http://onepresscommunity.com/)
- [Starkers](http://elliotjaystocks.com/blog/free-starkers-wordpress-theme/)
- [Startbox](http://wpstartbox.com)
- [Starter Theme Project](http://wpcandy.com/uncategorized/the-wordpress-starter-theme-project)
- [Vanilla](http://code.google.com/p/vanilla-theme/)
- [Whiteboard](http://plainbeta.com/2008/05/20/whiteboard-a-free-wordpress-theme-framework/)
- [WordPreciousss](http://wordpreciousss.org/)
- [wp-constructor](http://code.google.com/p/wp-constructor/)

If that's not what you meant, please clarify.

Comment: Could you please recommend the one which would be good for someone who is completely new to WP theme development...

Comment: @Shubhkarman - heh, that's a loaded question! Kinda like asking which religion is right for someone wanting to get more in tune with their spiritual side. :-)

Seriously, but "new to theme development", what do you mean? What are your goals? And what are your current skills and expertise?

Comment: I know XHTML and CSS and a fair amount of Javascript. I know a little of PHP too.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - I'd add on Startbox (http://wpstartbox.com/), mostly because I helped beta test it.

Comment: @John P Bloch - Done! 
@Shubhkarman - I've got to run to present WordPress Answers to Atlanta WordPress Meetup but will reply soon.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel OK.....

Comment: @Shubhkarman I can only really answer which one I'd probably start with and that's Thematic but only because the person who developed it has a stellar reputation. The reality is we probably need to sit down and do a detailed analysis of each one.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - some like "Brave New World" shouldn't imo be in the list. The one named copied the whole functions.php from tewenty ten and even uses 'twenty_ten' as it's textdomain. It can't compete with any other one on the list. Just as a sidenote at poeple who read this thread.